# Get value inside array and array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a similar array in the below format. I need to be able to find the object based on the `id` and it has to search for all the nested arrays (parent and child). And, the `selectedId` could be also be from the `id` of parent array.

Could anyone please advise?

Excerpt from my code

```js
const cars = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'toyota',
  subs: [{
    id: 43,
    name: 'supra'
  }, {
    id: 44,
    name: 'prius'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Jeep',
  subs: [{
    id: 30,
    name: 'wranger'
  }, {
    id: 31,
    name: 'sahara'
  }]
}]
const selectedId = 31;
const result = cars.find((val) => val.subs.id === selectedId)
console.log(result)
```

My expected output should be

```
{id: 31, name: 'sahara'}
```

Comment: `val.subs.id` is undefined because `subs` is an array, you'll need another bit of logic to check the inner array

Comment: `const result = cars.find(({id,subs}) => id === selectedId || subs.find(({id})=> id === selectedId))`

Comment: @Anon but that checks only for subs id right? I can just add an or condition inside find for checking for parent ids too?

Comment: i think that works if you put the or on the first find

Comment: I'd recommend writing your own `for`-`of` loop in this situation, since the existing array methods don't really work for this.

Comment: `const result = cars.find((val, i) => val.subs[i].id === selectedId || val.id === selectedId)`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938203/javascript-recursive-search-on-an-array-of-objects/75440755#75440755